# Error when Compiling CPython: C2440 'function': cannot convert from 'PyObject' to PyObject *'

Tags: c, cpython

I'm new to using CPython (and C as well) and I was trying to create an extension module to calculate nCk. However, I'm coming across this really annoying error when compiling. Here's my code:

```c
PyObject* combination(PyObject* n, PyObject* k){
    PyObject* output = ONE;
    return PyNumber_TrueDivide(factorial(n), PyNumber_Multiply(factorial(k), factorial(PyNumber_Subtract(n, k))));
}
```

```c
static PyObject* BezierCurve_combination(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    PyObject n, k;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &n, &k))
        return NULL;
    
    /* This return statement is line 60*/
    return Py_BuildValue("O", combination(n, k));
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
(60): error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'PyObject' to 'PyObject *'
(60): warning C4024: 'combination': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
(60): warning C4024: 'combination': different types for formal and actual parameter 2
```

What is causing this error? A similar program works really well for a factorial function definition (it contains just 1 `PyObject*` argument.) How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when compiling CPython: Cannot Convert from PyLongObject to PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978464/error-when-compiling-cpython-cannot-convert-from-pylongobject-to-pyobject)

Comment: Nope, that was one of my own questions.

Comment: That was exactly my point. The issue is the same: you should pass a pointer.

Comment: @ead I understood that after the last question. Here, the issue was with using the `*` with a space after because I thought that `PyObject*` created a Pointer, not `*n, *k`. Yes, the errors were the same, but the reason behind them were different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never have a `PyObject` in your program like that. They're always *pointers* to `PyObject`s.

Use `PyObject *n, *k;` - or, if in doubt,

```
PyObject *n;
PyObject *k;
```

---

Furthermore, you must **always** check the return value of **each** and **every** function in a Python exception, excepting if you're just returning it from your function. Thus you **may not write**

```
return PyNumber_TrueDivide(factorial(n),
       PyNumber_Multiply(factorial(k), factorial(PyNumber_Subtract(n, k))));
```

You can only write

```
return PyNumber_TrueDivide(dividend, divisor);
```

For the inner calls you **must** check that they're not NULL separately, and if they are it signifies an exception that you must handle, or throw out (by returning NULL from your function).

Comment: Ohh, I see. I had done `PyObject* n, k` before in hopes of it working because I thought `PyObject*` made `n` & `k` pointers. I suppose it is `*n` and `*k` that make it pointers. This is why it must have worked in the factorial code where I just did `PyObject* n`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll accept your answer in about 10 mins, Stackoverflow has a time-limit before I can do so.

Comment: @BhavyeMathur that's why in C we indeed write `PyObject *n, *k`, putting the space before the typename.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll change that elsewhere in the code (and do the NULL checks too).